# script has two running processes with different PIDs (always a difference of 4)

Tags: linux, shell

I have a ksh script that calls other scripts. The initial script only makes one call to the second script. However, if I do "ps axwww | grep full_script_name | grep -v grep", it shows 2 instances of the second script, both with different PIDs. And the PIDs are always 4 numbers off from each other (eg 22089 and 22093).

Why is this happening?

Comment: What does the other script do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, it won't always be 4 off, because eventually it will run into some PIDs that are still allocated. But this is probably the scenario, or at least close to it:

- Start `script.ksh` - get PID 42
- `script.ksh` calls an external program, which gets PID 43, then exits and returns control to the script
- `script.ksh` calls a second external program, which gets PID 44
- `script.ksh` calls a third external program, getting PID 45
- `script.ksh` calls `child-script.ksh`, which gets PID 46, and hangs around while you run `ps`

"External programs" are numerous - everything from `ls` to `awk`, `sed`, `perl`, `sort`......

Comment: The difference might be more than 4 because other users on the machine ran commands, or `cron` did, or someone connected remotely, or you're running a compilation in another window, or ... On some systems (not Linux), PIDs are allocated at random rather than sequentially.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Yep, those are other good reasons... Didn't really focus on that bit, as it didn't seem to be the main question...